ValueError(f"Missing some input keys: {missing_keys}")
I am facing an error:
ValueError(f"Missing some input keys: {missing_keys}")

from this code. I am trying to parse resumes that are not supposed to have the keywords Name, phone, about_me in them.
However, it parses the keyword it finds similar to the Pydantic class, if prompt is used where I mention setting the field to null if the fields have no information.
Traceback:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Sarthak\PycharmProjects\API Resume parser\main.py", line 188, in <module>
    info = ExtractInformationFromResume(extracted_text)
  File "C:\Users\Sarthak\PycharmProjects\API Resume parser\main.py", line 120, in ExtractInformationFromResume
    response = chain.run({"resume": resume})
  File "C:\Users\Sarthak\PycharmProjects\API Resume parser\venv\lib\site-packages\langchain_core\_api\deprecation.py", line 179, in warning_emitting_wrapper
    return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Sarthak\PycharmProjects\API Resume parser\venv\lib\site-packages\langchain\chains\base.py", line 606, in run
    return self(args[0], callbacks=callbacks, tags=tags, metadata=metadata)[
  File "C:\Users\Sarthak\PycharmProjects\API Resume parser\venv\lib\site-packages\langchain_core\_api\deprecation.py", line 179, in warning_emitting_wrapper
    return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Sarthak\PycharmProjects\API Resume parser\venv\lib\site-packages\langchain\chains\base.py", line 389, in __call__
    return self.invoke(
  File "C:\Users\Sarthak\PycharmProjects\API Resume parser\venv\lib\site-packages\langchain\chains\base.py", line 170, in invoke
    raise e
  File "C:\Users\Sarthak\PycharmProjects\API Resume parser\venv\lib\site-packages\langchain\chains\base.py", line 158, in invoke
    self._validate_inputs(inputs)
  File "C:\Users\Sarthak\PycharmProjects\API Resume parser\venv\lib\site-packages\langchain\chains\base.py", line 290, in _validate_inputs
    raise ValueError(f"Missing some input keys: {missing_keys}")
ValueError: Missing some input keys: {'\n    "ContactInformation"'}

class ContactInformation(BaseModel):
    Name: Optional[str] = None
    Email: Optional[str] = None
    Contact: Optional[str] = None
    Links: Optional[List[str]] = None

class Experience(BaseModel):
    title: Optional[str] = None
    company: Optional[str] = None
    duration: Optional[str] = None

class Education(BaseModel):
    course: Optional[str] = None
    branch: Optional[str] = None
    institute: Optional[str] = None

class Projects(BaseModel):
    name: Optional[str] = None
    description: Optional[str] = None
    link: Optional[str] = None

class OutputFormat(BaseModel):
    ContactInformation: Optional[ContactInformation] = None
    About_Me: Optional[str] = None
    Experience: Optional[Union[None, List[Experience]]] = None
    Education: Optional[Union[None, List[Education]]] = None
    Skills: Optional[List[str]] = None
    Certificates: Optional[List[str]] = None
    Projects: Optional[Union[None, List[Projects]]] = None
    Achievements: Optional[List[str]] = None
    Volunteer: Optional[List[str]] = None

Prompt:
PROMPT_2 = """You are given resume : ```{resume}```

Based on the given resume, extract information about the person.

The output should strictly follow the JSON schema below. If a field does not have information, set it to null. Ensure that the email contains an "@" symbol and the contact number is a string of digits. The name is usually found at the beginning of the resume without any labels. Social links should be valid URLs.

{
    "ContactInformation": {
        "Name": string, // Name of the person, usually at the beginning
        "Email": string, // Email address containing "@"
        "Contact": string, // Contact number as a string of digits
        "Links": [string] // Array of social profile URLs
    },
    "About_Me": string, // A brief summary about the person
    "Experience": [
        {
            "title": string, // Title of the position
            "company": string, // Company name
            "duration": string // Duration of employment
        }
    ],
    "Education": [
        {
            "course": string, // Name of the course or subject studied
            "branch": string, // Branch or faculty of study
            "institute": string // Name of the educational institute
        }
    ],
    "Skills": [string], // Array of skills
    "Certificates": [string], // Array of certificates
    "Projects": [
        {
            "name": string, // Name of the project
            "description": string, // Description of the project
            "link": string // URL to the project
        }
    ],
    "Achievements": [string], // Array of achievements
    "Volunteer": [string] // Array of volunteer work
}
"""

ExtractInformationFromResume function:
def ExtractInformationFromResume(resume: str) -> OutputFormat:
    llm = ChatOpenAI(
        openai_api_key='*********************************************',
        temperature=0.5,
        model_name="gpt-3.5-turbo"
    )

    # Define the output parser
    parser = PydanticOutputParser(pydantic_object=OutputFormat)

    # Create the prompt template with format instructions
    prompt_template = PromptTemplate(
        input_variables=["resume"],
        template=PROMPT_2,
        partial_variables={"format_instructions": parser.get_format_instructions()},
    )

    # Chain the LLM with the prompt
    chain = LLMChain(llm=llm, prompt=prompt_template)

    # Run the chain with the resume as input
    print(f"Resume Length: {len(resume)} characters")
    response = chain.run({"resume": resume})
    try:
        print("Raw LLM Response:", response)
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error: {str(e)}")

    # Parse the LLM response into the expected output format
    try:
        return OutputFormat(**json.loads(response))
    except json.JSONDecodeError:
        raise ValueError("Failed to parse response as valid JSON: " + response)


Can you add a full traceback please and rest of the Pydantic model.

@dkasa
I have added.

Please provide a [mre], with emphasis on minimal. Most of your model and code is not necessary to reproduce the problem, and having more code makes what you have harder to parse.

Add print for resume and check that resume.get("ContactInformation") != None. You could add that check before response = chain.run({"resume": resume})
